# How to get the unmatched records from two tables using Joins

Tags: sql

I have two tables one is teacher and another is Department which is mentioned below.

Teacher Table

```
Id Name 
1    xyz 
2.   Gjd
3.   Dftr
4    dhdk
```

Department Table

```
Id Name  EMPID
1    SQL.     2
2.   PHP.     4
3.   JAVA.   1
4    PEARL. 5
```

QUESTION 
i want those records of teacher which are not link with any Department.

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: I want data from Ist table i.e teacher table Those teacher record which not linked with any Department using joins not by correlated sub query.

Comment: Using Joins i want..

Answer (score 3):

you can use following statement using `left join` then filter Teacher that not matched

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM Teacher t
left join Department d on d.EMPID = t.Id 
where d.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE 
id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT EMPID FROM departments) ;
```

Hope this helps.!!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by inner query..

```
select * from teacher where id not in (select empid from department);
```